# Controlling console.log output with Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack-2

I recently upgraded to Webpack 2 and now all my console.logs in the browser disappeared, as well as all redux-logger outputs, and all JavaScript errors and warnings.

I have two configs - for dev and for test. They are virtually the same, but dev has console.logs and test doesn't. How do I enable them on test?

Here's dev that has console.logs:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: [
    'bootstrap-loader',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index',
  ],

  output: {
    publicPath: '/dist/',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader' },
        { loader: 'css-loader', options: { localIdentName: '[path][name]--[local]' } },
        { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { plugins: function () { return [ require('autoprefixer') ]; }}},
        { loader: 'sass-loader' },
      ]
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
      ],
    }],
  },

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: '/dist/',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: '"development"' },
      __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'bundle.css' }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Here's test, that doesn't, but should:

const webpack = require('webpack');
    const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: ['bootstrap-loader/extractStyles'],

  output: {
    publicPath: 'dist/',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader' },
        { loader: 'css-loader' },
        { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { plugins: function () { return [ require('autoprefixer') ]; }}},
        { loader: 'sass-loader' },
      ]
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
      ],
    }],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: '"test"' },
      __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'bundle.css' }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ sourceMap: true }),
  ],
};
```

Suspected Uglify plugin at first, tried removing it - no result. What gives?

Comment: What kind of `console.log`?  From your app (explicitly calling `console.log`) or from the build tool (e.g. HMR messages)?

Comment: Yeah, from the app, from redux-logger, etc. console.log visible in the browser

Answer (score -1):

In the test config the `entry` does not include your app. Therefore it doesn't get bundled and your `console.log`s won't be called as they don't exist, in fact your whole app is left out. So you need to include your app entry point in the test config as well:

```
entry: ['bootstrap-loader/extractStyles', './src/index'],
```

Comment: The app works fine though, just console.logs are not there. In fact everything worked fine on Webpack 1. Gonna try your thing, see what happens.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. But maybe you enabled `redux-logger` only in development (when `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`) as shown in [Log only in development](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger#log-only-in-development).

Comment: mine is predicate: () => ((process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') || (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test')) , so it should work for both. Everything worked until an upgrade to webpack 2, where I followed their migration guide, changing only the webpack configuration. And it's not just redux-logger - any JavaScript errors/warnings are suppressed too